# I am trying to place a button at the bottom of LinearLayout. But it's not showing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quantity" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Order" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am new in Android. And I am learning Android at Udacity. But the course is way old that some errors are happening. I am not able to handle the errors.

[image: screenshot for explanation]

Answer (score 3):

Change `quantity_text_view`'s layout_height from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Or, the TextView should occupy rest of the height after the first TextView.